# angular - set/edit route queries(or params) without navigating

Tags: angular, routes, routeparams

Hi I want to use routes to store certain information like pagination data or filter data in the queries (or params). For example I'm on

```
app/datagrid
```

and I want to add page=2 and pageSize=10 to it

```
app/datagrid?page=2&pageSize=10
```

Is there a way to edit/set them to the current route without triggering a route change/update?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are adding it to the current route, then the route will not change. It won't reload the component if only the parameters change.

You can see an example here: [Passing params angular 2 traditional way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44331189/passing-params-angular-2-traditional-way/44331724#44331724)

This uses the `.navigate` command, but if it is navigating to the same component it is currently displaying, it won't actually "navigate".

Alternatively, you could build a service that retains that data instead of using route parameters. I have an example here: https://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/build-a-simple-angular-service-to-share-data/

The service would basically look like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable() 
export class DataService {
  serviceData: string; 
}
```

But instead of `serviceData` you'd have your `page` and `pageSize`.