# How to get URL after equal in TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to get this token that is in the url, to send to db later

```
mysite.com/changePassword?token=45456112241121131154
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: if it's any url that you want to parse, have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript  If you want to parse current URL in a angular component/service, you can use angular's router

Comment: I wanted a way with the angular even so I created this topic

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44331189/passing-params-angular-2-traditional-way/44331724#44331724

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check with Activated route

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

ngOnInit() { 

  console.log(this.route.snapshot.queryParams["token"]); 

}
```